# NSNotification with multithreading XCODE

Tags: multithreading, nsnotification

I am a newbie to IPHONE development. I am facing a issue in working with NSNotification with multithreading.

I have a few images in a gallery.I select the image. Selected images get stored in core data.I have a button (upload). When i click on it i need to show a hud with a NSNotification saying (Uploading with image name). ie. "uploading image1.jpg" then i need to call the next thread to display "uploading image2.jpg" and so on. I need a sample code for this.

I need to know how to send and receive NSNotification with multithreading. Kindly help me in this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) for this.

The demo project include examples very similar to what you're doing.
The components also has other feature you may want, like a progress indicator.

From the main page, configuring an async task to have a HUD notification is as simple as:

```
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    // Do something...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    });
});
```

Comment: How can i add notification text to hud. I have a single hud and i need to call multiple threads. hud with multiple thread text.

Comment: Build the sample project, you'll see how easy it is to add different text. For multiple threads, maybe one master thread that spawns the others and updates the display.